# Convergence proof based on another sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $y_n = \frac{10}{x_n^2}$ for all $n \in N$, then $y_n \rightarrow 0$.

I'm struggling here. Clearly I have to show $|\frac{10}{x_n^2}-0|<\epsilon$ but I don't know what to choose for k such that n>k implies this is true.

I had tried k=$\sqrt{\frac{10}{\epsilon}}$ but that only proved it for $|\frac{10}{n^2}-0|<\epsilon$. Not sure how to get started with two sequences involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, since $x_n \to \infty, \exists N: n > N \to x_n > \sqrt{\dfrac{10}{\epsilon}} \to \left|y_n-0\right| = \left|\frac{10}{x_n^2} - 0\right| < \epsilon$